# How to denote an event that is always true?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, notation, article-writing

What is a good symbol to denote an event that is always true? It is a good way to use the symbol of the probability space, e.g. $\Omega$. But in my paper, the probability space is very complicated and I do not plan to discuss explicitly about it. For a normal event, I denote it with its condition, e.g. $\{X>0\}$. But for an event that is always true in the probability space, I cannot find a good way to denote it — it also looks confusing to use something like $\{1>0\}$.

Comment: By "always true," do you mean that for e.g. an event $E$, $$\mathbb P\left(\omega\in\Omega : \mathsf 1_E(\omega) = 1\right) = 1 $$ or $$\mathsf 1_E(\omega) = 1,\quad \forall\ \omega\in\Omega\  $$ $\Large \mathrm?\\ $

Comment: Thank for reply. I mean the latter. Maybe I should say "the" event that is always true.

Comment: In that case you are describing precisely the **sample space** $\Omega$.

Comment: Yes. But In my paper, I did not define the space $\Omega$. I am analyzing a random process, so the space is very complicated. It is not convenient to formally define this space.

Comment: You should nevertheless go for the notation $\Omega$ since one does not need to identify $\Omega$ to work with the probability measure $P$ on $\Omega$. Note that the random process you are studying only requires the latter, not the former.

Answer (score 1):

> Here are two admittedly somewhat contrived variants:
>
> - The *empty condition* $$\{\}$$  is vacuously true.
> - The *[Iverson brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket)* are defined as
>     \begin{align*}
>   [[P(x)]]=\begin{cases}
>   1&\qquad P(x) \ \text{  true}\\
>   0&\qquad P(x) \ \text{ false}
>   \end{cases}
>   \end{align*}
>
>   A statement which is always true can be written as $[[1]]$. So, instead of $\{1>0\}$ we could also write
>     \begin{align*}
>   \{[[1]]\}
>   \end{align*}

Comment: "Contrived" indeed. (Never saw any of these, used to denote the full space.)