# What are some good texts/notes on the construction of probability spaces for stochastic processes?

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, stochastic-processes, constructive-mathematics

Often in probability the underlying probability space is assumed to be implicit. That is, for a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$, one tends to write $\mathbb P(E)$ for $E\in\mathcal F$ rather than the precise expression $$ \mathbb P\left(\omega\in\Omega: \omega\in E \right), $$
for a random variable $X:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ it is standard to write e.g. $\mathbb P(X\leqslant x)$ as opposed to $$\mathbb P\left(\omega\in\Omega: X(\omega)\leqslant x\right), $$
and in particular, $\mathbb E[X]$ as $$\int_{\mathbb R} x\,\mathsf dF(x) $$ as opposed to $$\int_\Omega X(\omega)\,\mathsf d\mathbb P(\omega). $$
For discrete distributions, this is a moot point, as $\Omega$ is at most countable and so we may simply take $\mathcal F=2^\Omega$ and fully characterize the distribution of a random variable $X$ by its probability mass function $\{p_n\}$, i.e. if $\{x_n\}$ is an enumeration of $E=X(\Omega)$ then $\{p_n\}$ is the unique positive sequence such that $p_n=\mathbb P(X=x_n)$.

But in more general settings, the sample space $\Omega$, $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal F$ and probability measure $\mathbb P$ are typically not explicitly defined, as [this example.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2010173/how-to-denote-an-event-that-is-always-true) It is well known that the finite sum of i.i.d. Bernoulli random variables has a binomial distribution, but the converse is not true, as shown in [this example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1920276/is-a-binomial-a-sum-of-bernoulli-random-variables), in which user @Did gave examples of conditions on the probability space in which a binomial random variable could or could not be written as the sum of Bernoulli random variables.

I recently acquired the texts *Topics in the Constructive Theory of Countable Markov Chains* by Foayolle et al. and *Theory of Markov Processes* by Dynkin. These are quite advanced texts, however, so I would appreciate any recommendations for more elementary treatment of this topic - and in particular that are not focused specifically on Markov processes.

Comment: Please see whether this helps you: http://home.in.tum.de/~immler/mastersthesis/thesis.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[From here](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=YbDACwAAQBAJ&dq=construction+of+probability+spaces+for+stochastic+processes&source=gbs_navlinks_s)**:

---

In Kolmogorov's construction of the probability space for a stochastic process the space of elementary events $\Omega$ is selected as the set of all trajectories $t \to \omega(t)$. The random variable $a_t$ is defined as $$a_t(\omega) = \omega(t)$$ Construction of the probability measure $P$ serving all finite random vectors is a mathematically sophisticated task going back to construction of the Wiener measure on the space of continuous functions.

Thus, the Kolmogorov construction of a stochastic process is based not on "hidden variables"(e.g. the initial conditions) determining in advance future results of measurements, but rather on the results themselves.

---

And I also hope [this PDF](http://home.in.tum.de/~immler/mastersthesis/thesis.pdf) will be useful for you. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, @Rohan. It will take some time to digest that thesis, but it is definitely along the lines of what I was looking for.